I can't find my page on facebook page token on Facebook Graph API Explorer
I am trying to use Facebook Graph API Explorer to get a page access token to a specific page.

But upon selecting the page I need, I am redirected to this new chrome tab:

And after clicking "Done", I don't see this page inside the "Get Token" tab

while finding solution, I read here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens/ that to obtain a page access token, I need to start obtaining a user access token

So here is what I did,I clicked "Get user access token"

I did the same thing, I authorized everything and clicked "Done" but the page is still not in the "Get Token" Tab.
I own and created this pages and I have connected it to my business portfolio in https://business.facebook.com/ using the same business I am using with the meta developer app but for some reason it's not appearing in Facebook Graph API Explorer. Please help me get access this pages in graph API Explorer. Thank you

I figured it out. I followed the instructions here
https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/396863449972483/
